# Adicionar uma barra de rolagem em uma DIV

Tags: html

Tenho um menu no mobile com algumas opções, só tem um problema, quando eu estou mexendo pelo celular ele abre normal, mas quando eu tento ver todas as opções rolando para baixo ele rola a pagina inicial e não o menu. Como faço para adicionar um scroll no menu e pausar o da pagina quando ele estiver ativo? Se observarem a imagem vão conseguir ver o scroll >
mas o menu não rola, não mostrando seu conteúdo, ele rola a pagina atras dessa.
**Edit:** o header é fixo, para descer junto com a rolagem da pagina. E como o conteúdo do menu está acoplado ao header ele não desce, gostaria de saber se tem como eu colocar um scroll só para este menu, quando o menu estiver aberto pausar o scroll da pagina.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.menu{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.


</div>
```

Para colocar um `scroll` em uma div, basta fazer assim.